# Array of string with Realm database .NET sdk

Tags: .net, mongodb, realm

My Realm schema define a property as array of string. I add this property in my .NET model as a `RealmList<string>` but this is always an empty list. I also try with an `IList<string>` but I have a `null` value.

Someone already try to map a list of primitive instead of a list of `EmbeddedObject` or `RealmObject`?

My schema:

```json
{
  "title": "simple",
  "bsonType": "object",
  "properties": {
    "_id": {
      "bsonType": "objectId"
    },
    "_partition": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "name": {
      "bsonType": "string"
    },
    "hashtags": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "string"
      }
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "_id",
    "_partition",
    "name"
  ]
}
```

An example of data stored

```json
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6151a0eb49d3cbc1b3795579"
    },
    "_partition": "Part001",
    "name": "First obj",
    "hashtags": ["001", "0003"]
}
```

My .NET model:

```cs
[MapTo("simple")]
public class Simple : RealmObject
{
  [PrimaryKey]
  [MapTo("_id")]
  public ObjectId Id { get; set; } = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();

  [Required]
  [MapTo("_partition")]
  public string Partition { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [MapTo("name")]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [MapTo("hashtags")]
  public RealmList<string> Hashtags { get; }
}
```

.NET code that load data

```cs
var app = App.Create("my-realm");

var user = await app.LogInAsync(Credentials.EmailPassword("", ""));

var configuration = new SyncConfiguration("Part001", user)
{
  ObjectClasses = new[] { typeof(Simple) }
};

var realm = await Realm.GetInstanceAsync(configuration);
await realm.GetSession().WaitForDownloadAsync();
await realm.GetSession().WaitForUploadAsync();

var simples = realm.All<Simple>().ToList();
```

Comment: Perhaps re-reading the documentation on [List](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/dotnet/data-types/collections/#collections---.net-sdk) objects would help. It says - *create a List collection by defining a getter-only property of type IList<T>*. - And then - *Local-only Realm Databases support collections of nullable (optional) values, but Sync does not.*-  Meaning that this section of the docs - *add the [Required] attribute if the list contains nullable reference types, such as string or byte[]* - is relevant

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it to use IList and ISet when I use an unique constraint for array.

```cs
[MapTo("simple")]
public class Simple : RealmObject
{
  [PrimaryKey]
  [MapTo("_id")]
  public ObjectId Id { get; set; } = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();

  [Required]
  [MapTo("_partition")]
  public string Partition { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [MapTo("name")]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [MapTo("hashtags")]
  public IList<string> Hashtags { get; }

  // If I use "uniqueItems": true in my schema
  // "hashtags": {
  //  "bsonType": "array",
  //  "uniqueItems": true,
  //  "items": {
  //    "bsonType": "string"
  //  }
  // }
  // [Required]
  // [MapTo("hashtags")]
  // public ISet<string> Hashtags { get; }
}
```